# Safari 5.1 npapi issue

Tags: cocoa, safari, npapi

Since several days I am trying to resolve the folowing issue, reading all I found around the web about npapi on mac.

The goal is to have a npapi plugin which works for safari and firefox(mac).
My software (that I can not rewrite specialy for this purpose hase about 45000 lines of C code) is based on a NSView attached to a NSDocument....

I have a webkit version based plugin that I must trash (thanks to Apple!) based to the same NSView.

I have a npapi version plugin which works fine on firefox. In this npapi plugin, I take the carbon window ref, I make a NSWindow based on that:
    NSWindow *browserWindow = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithWindowRef:wind]autorelease];

and I put my NSView on this window and that works.

Now the pb is that I can not do the same thing on safari.

Look at attached picture, the window is not in the safari's window!
[image: the firefox window is between safari's window and my plugin window]

I tryed several ways... it dose not work.
Can a cocoa's gourou says where I am making something wrong? or is this a known issue?

NPError NPP_SetWindow(NPP instance, NPWindow* window){

NP_CGContext *ctx = window->window;
  void *wind = ctx->window;

...
in the NSView init function:

```
NSWindow *browserWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithWindowRef:wind];
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if( self )
{
    [browserWindow makeFirstResponder: self];
    [self  setNextResponder: nil];
    [browserWindow setContentView:self];
    [self webPlugInInitialize];// my own initializing
}
return self;
```

Comment: i don't think you can use `NSView` for firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Safari 5.1, the web rendering is not done by Safari itself, but on a different process to enhance security.  Open up the Activity Monitor, and you see that background process called "Safari Web Process" or something like that.

So, you can't and shouldn't create `NSWindow` based on the Carbon window ref which can be obtained within NPAPI plugin. 
Read [Apple's own documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/Tasks/NetscapePlugins.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001250-BAJGJJAH) on this point. You should request the core graphics drawing method, and then the `WindowRef` field of `NP_CGContext` should have a `NSWindow*`, not the Carbon window ref.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give enough code line, in fact window->window is the NP_CGContext inside what I take the wind. But it is not the NSWindow, it is HIObject, the carbon window ref which I use.

Comment: Of course I have asked for core graphics. I tryed also with cocoa events, safari gives ctx->window with Nil value, no way to add any NSView somewhere with cocoa events model

Comment: Then I guess you can't use NSView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Has somebody an idea for changing the NSWindow's behaviour? I repeat that it works under Firefox!

Comment: It works on Firefox, because in that case the plugin still runs "within" Firefox. In Safari, the plugin is not part of Safari process anymore.  So your plugin can't access Safari's window. So, the fact it works on Firefox doesn't mean anything on the new Safari.

Comment: It works in Firefox because of a fluke and a coincidence in how Firefox's private implementation works. It will not work in the latest firefox on most machines because those run in a seperate process like Safari plugins do. Chrome won't work either

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will say to my customer that his software will not be supported anymore by safari, chrome and more and more multiprocess navigators. One open a time a NSView based software was the right approch in Cocoa for having a software's kernel wich can be be used easily to have plug-in. Today we need a new approch for our new softwars, or stupidly rewrite them each time.

Comment: Was it so important for your customer to embed the view into the browser? It only works in Mac in any case. Why was an stand-alone app not adequate in your situation? I'm just curious.

Comment: Yes it is very important. The stand alone app existes (based on the same NSView). Imagine that my plugin shows a kind of movie and you need comment an movie maker career on a html document with a few seconds of the scene you are talking about as sample....It is also important because his customer pay him for that service, and he can pay me for having that on macOSX.

Comment: @Freddie I see. Anyway, generic browser plugins are going away in general; you need to come up with something else. Things change.

Answer (score 2):

If it works on Firefox, that's totally shocking and completely unsupported. Does it work in Firefox 4 and later?

If you absolutely have to use an NSView, the only way that I know to do it in a plugin is to render the NSView into your CGContext. Keep in mind that in newer NPAPI browsers with the Cocoa event system you get the CGContextRef as part of the draw event; to request a draw event you can call NPN_InvalidateWindow.

FireBreath has a [completely experimental and not-fully-functional example of rendering an NSView](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/libs/WebView/Mac/WebViewMac.mm) (ans specifically a WebView) into a CGContextRef that you could look at as an example.

Other than using a CGContextRef your only other choice is to use a CALayer; if you can find a way to make a NSWindow or NSView in that you could be okay, but I don't know if there is one.  Someone suggested that setting the CALayer as the rendering layer for the NSView might work. Either way you'll most likely have to forward all the events since you are basically hosting the NSView in an offscreen view.

Make no mistake; there *is* no supported way to get an NSView in the browser. There never has been -- methods that people have used were unsupported and depended on browser-specific implementations of the API. When you use things like that, you can reliably expect them to eventually break, such as in this case.  For more information on the drawing models, you could [read Stuart Morgan's blog post on the subject](http://www.escapedthoughts.com/weblog/geek/P110308-mac-npapi-plugins.writeback), check out the [FireBreath mac drawing model docs](http://www.firebreath.org/x/PYBR), or read the [Cocoa event model spec](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aCocoaEventModel).

Comment: There is no way to put an NSWindow or NSView into a CALayer. You could draw the contents of an NSView into a CALayer, just as you could draw to a CGContextRef, but either way it's just a picture of it, and would thus (as you say) require event forwarding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will say to my customer that his software will not be supported anymore by safari, chrome and more and more multiprocess navigators. One open a time a NSView based software was the right approch in Cocoa for having a software's kernel wich can be be used easily to have plug-in. Today we need a new approch for our new softwars, or stupidly rewrite them each time.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you start with "take the carbon window ref", your approach is doomed, because it is based on the Carbon event model (and not just that, but assumptions about its internal implementation details). Anyone running Firefox on a 64-bit system will have to manually restart Firefox in 32-bit mode for your hack to work, and even then it will only work until Firefox completely removes Carbon support (which is planned for the foreseeable future).

As the other answers said, where you are going wrong is that your whole approach is completely unsupported, and the fact that it ever worked at all as an NPAPI plugin was luck. You simply cannot use an NSView directly in an NPAPI plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will say to my customer that his software will not be supported anymore by safari, chrome and more and more multiprocess navigators. One open a time a NSView based software was the right approch in Cocoa for having a software's kernel wich can be be used easily to have plug-in. Today we need a new approch for our new softwars, or stupidly rewrite them each time.